# Local instance of Databricks for development

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, aws-databricks

I am currently working on a small team that is developing a Databricks based solution.  For now we are small enough to work off of cloud instances of Databricks.  As the group grows this will not really be practical.

Is there a "local" install of Databricks that can be installed for development purposes (it doesn't need to be a scalable version but does need to be essentially fully featured)?  In other words, is there a way each developer can create their own development instance of Databricks on their local machine?

Is there another way to provide a dedicated Databricks environment for each developer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Databricks, as a cloud-deployed platform, leverages many cloud technologies in its deployment.  For example, [Auto Loader](https://docs.databricks.com/ingestion/auto-loader/index.html) incrementally ingests new data files as they arrive in AWS using EventBridge, SNS and S3, while Azure uses EventHubs, Notification Hubs and ADLS technologies.  They aim to create a seamless look and feel across AWS, Azure and GCP but can do this only in the cloud.

For local deployment, you may be able to use [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/) and [MlFlow](https://mlflow.org/) and create a similar experience, but the notebook experience isn't open source.  The workflow of Databricks is proprietary, though Databricks has open-sourced many of its technologies, like [Delta Lake](https://delta.io/).  The local Spark, MlFlow, may suffice for some and then use the cloud sparingly, but the seamless workflow offered by Databricks is challenging to replicate outside of the leading cloud vendors.